# JQuery Select2 Tags On Form Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am writing a WebForm using jquery and the multi select2 tag tool. Users select mutiple agencies from the drop down, save, and the data is stored to a back end SQL database as a single string in the following pipe delimited format: [AGENCY1|AGENCY2|AGENCY3].

```
<input id="ddlAgency" type="hidden" class="form-control" value="" name="select2tag"/>
```

When the form loads, I am able to parse through the tags, but how do I get them to display as selected in the select2 multiple form control (ie: AGENECY1, AGENECY2, AGENECY3 appear as selected tags, while the rest of the options are selectable in the dropdown)?

```
var agencySplit = row.INC_AGENCY.split("|");
for (var i = 0; i < agencySplit.length; i++) {
    $('#ddlAgency').val(agencySplit[i]);  //This Doesn't Work Like I Want It To
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the items from your split as `option` to your `select` element.

```
<select id="ddlAgency" style="width:300px" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="select2tag"/>

$('select').select2();

var agency = "AGENCY1|AGENCY2|AGENCY3";
var agencySplit = agency.split("|");
for (var i = 0; i < agencySplit.length; i++) {
    $('#ddlAgency').append("<option>" + agencySplit[i] + "</option>");  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c1ozynyu/

If doing multi-select :

```
$('select').select2({multiple: true});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c1ozynyu/1/

UPDATED : ( Based on the comments to pre select items in the list )

```
<select id="ddlAgency" style="width:300px" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="select2tag">
    <option val="AGENCY1">AGENCY1</option>
    <option val="AGENCY2">AGENCY2</option>
    <option val="AGENCY3">AGENCY3</option>
    <option val="AGENCY4">AGENCY4</option>
    <option val="AGENCY5">AGENCY5</option>
</select>

var array = new Array();
var agency = "AGENCY1|AGENCY2|AGENCY3";
var agencySplit = agency.split("|");
for (var i = 0; i < agencySplit.length; i++) {
    array.push(agencySplit[i]);   
}
$('select').select2({multiple: true}).select2('val', array);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c1ozynyu/2/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This is close, but what I want is all three items to be selected in the text box. There may be other agencies in the drop down (ie: AGENCY4, AGENCY5, ...), but the three selected from the database are already selected.

Comment: Everything seems to work in jFiddle. But in my application, i get the following error: _Option 'multiple' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element._

Any ideas? Officially your code works so I will mark it as correct, just seeing if you have any ideas.

Comment: That being said, I get the error, but if I ignore the message, it behaves as expected. Thank you for your help!